# What is the easiest way to ODS a variable's value to an rtf file in SAS

Tags: sas

What is the easiest way to ODS a variable's value to an rtf file 
without tables or columns displayed. 
I would prefer not to have to use macros to do this also if it is possible.

Thanks in advance my friends

Comment: Do you want an rtf file with nothing in it except the value in question, or do you want to be able to place the value within a more complex rtf? Does the value need to placed inline with existing text?

Comment: Yes you are right I would like to be able to place the value within a more complex rtf among various text. It does indeed need to be placed inline with existing text

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

```
ods proctitle=no;
options nodate nonumber;
title;
ods rtf file="d:\temp\test.rtf" style=minimal;

proc print data=sashelp.class(where=(name='Alfred')) noobs label style={borderstyle=none}; 
  var age;
  label age='00'x;
run;

data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  where name='Alfred';
  declare odsout ODS();
  ods.format_text(data:age);
run;


ods rtf close;
```

The latter does exactly what you want, but isn't exactly supported for RTF (see the log).  The former does more or less what you want; there is still a header row, but it's blank.

As pointed out in comments, this is not exactly the same question if there is more context to this.

Answer (score 0):

If ODS is not a requirement, and you are just after the *simplest* and fastest method, you could always write the values directly to a file with a .rtf extension.  This would result in the cleanest RTF output as well if that is desired.

**Simple version:**

```
data _null_;
  file "c:\test.rtf";
  put "Hello";
run;
```

Depends on who the recipient of the file and how they are going to consume it among other things.  The file produced will open perfectly fine in say Word and probably most .RTF readers.

**More complex versions:**

If you need valid .RTF syntax, you could also add the minimum syntax for a valid RTF, which from what I can gather would look something like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\f0
Hello
}
```

Code to produce the above:

```
data _null_;
  file "c:\test.rtf";
  put "{\rtf1\ansi\f0";
  put "Hello";
  put "}";
run;
```

If you had a variable in a table you could print them all to an .rtf file like this:

```
data _null_;
  file "c:\test.rtf";
  set mytable end=eof;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    put "{\rtf1\ansi\f0";
  end;
  put my_variable;
  if eof then do;
    put "}";
  end;
run;
```

References used: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm and wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have some other text that's going into your rtf and you need your variable's value to be placed inline, then I think the most sensible approach is to store the value in a macro variable and put that in the middle of the text in your rtf. If you are keen to keep macro logic to a minimum, you can generate the macro variable via *call symput* in a data step or *select into* via proc sql depending on your preference. E.g.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select Age
    into :Alfred_age 
    from sashelp.class 
    where name = 'Alfred';
quit;

ods listing close;
ods rtf file = "C:\temp\test1.rtf";

ods rtf text = "Alfred's age is %sysfunc(strip(&Alfred_age)).";

ods rtf close;
ods listing;
```